# JSP still creates jsessionID with session=false

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat

I have a jsp page that returns content that is displayed on a HTTP page, the rest of my application is HTTPS.

Now when I browse from my HTTPS to my jsp on the HTTP page, I lose my cookie (cookie from HTTPS is secure and that's not allowed in HTTP pages). So then I added **session=false** in my jsp page header but when I call my jsp I still receive a JSESSIONID and I think I don't want that.

Because if the jsessionid from the http page is different than the one from https I get logged out.

So how do I prevent JSP from making a JSESSIONID?

ps: I am using tomcat 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive `<@page session="false">` will eliminate the automatic creation of an HTTP session when you access to a JSP page.
See for the details:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97688_16/generic.903/bp/j2ee.htm#1008677

Clarification: if you access other pages (or resources) that create an HTTP session and then you access the page with the directive `<@page session="false">` the session will not be destroyed.

Comment: Already tried that, JSP still sets a JSESSIONID cookie though :( But this was the general answer on the internet so I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks! I do not think that the session is created when you access JSP with `<@page session="false">`.  I recommend to use Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) do understand better when the session is created.

Comment: Hey, I am facing same issue, even after adding <%@ page session="false" %> i.e. my session is getting created on my first jsp...how should I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that you have applied `<@page session="false">` to all the included jsps as well. If any of the included jsp does not has the same page attribute, the parent jsp will still create the session.